# Where does SWT write dll files on windows?

Tags: java, windows, dll, swt

I cannot find on the Internet where SWT tries to write the dll files. I have a computer where the jar does not run only because SWT cannot write DLLs.

UPDATE 1

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
                at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
                at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
                at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.executeApplication(Unknown Source)
                at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.executeMainClass(Unknown Source)
                at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.doLaunchApp(Unknown Source)
                at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.run(Unknown Source)
                at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Could not load SWT library. Reasons:
                no swt-win32-3738 in java.library.path
                no swt-win32 in java.library.path
                Can't load library: \\ubz01fst\Students\User2010\Com\xxx\swt-win32-3738.dll
                Can't load library: \\ubz01fst\Students\User2010\Com\xxx\swt-win32.dll

                at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Library.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
                at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Library.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
                at org.eclipse.swt.internal.C.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
                at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
                at install.Main.main(Main.java:162)
```

Comment: a SWT is not SUPPOSED to be writing DLLs.

Comment: well, as written here (http://www.eclipse.org/swt/faq.php) it does, and I also get an error that shows that it creates dlls.

Comment: AAH in your own build environment using eclipse... WELL if you read the VERY link you provided to me carefully "Run the build command (sh build.sh for UNIX and Linux platforms, build.bat for Windows). This will create the appropriate library file(s) in the __current directory__."

Comment: no, wait: I have 2 Machines. in the first The jar works properly and when running creates under c:\Users\myuser\.swt\win\x86 the file dll. on the second it gives me the exception i wrote in the update 1.

Comment: Do you have the DLLs in your jar file's manifest ? typically inside lib/  with the jar.

Comment: I donno, I cannot understand where these dll files come from and under which environment variable are written

Comment: @hurtledown SWT is calling the DLL's via the JNI. Its a simple local path issue. Your error message shows you what it was expecting and where it couldn't find them. Unzip the jar and make sure everything is included.  On a separate note SWT is a native implementation as opposed to Swing  (which eventually ends up native, but is part of the Java distribution). Its a path issue usually ./lib/*DLLs as listed. '\\ubz01fst\Students\User2010\Com\xxx\swt-win32.dll' is a dead give-away.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I find out the answer myself.
Since SWT 3.3 you don't have to include the native (DLL) library anymore, because they are in the jar itself and they are unpacked as soon as the SWT library is called.
The DLL files are unpacked from the jar and placed in the ".swt" folder under your "System.getProperty("user.home")".
In my case the problem was that System.getProperty("user.home") is set to "\ubz01fst\Students\User2010\Com\xxx" which is a UNC path and that is not writable ( this often happen in companies or organizations computers ).

I donno for which reason the System.getProperty("user.home") in computers is taken from the environment variable "HOMESHARE" of Windows

The solution consists in changing the System.getProperty("user.home") with a writable path, for example:

```
System.setProperty("user.home", System.getenv("USERPROFILE"));
```

before calling any SWT code.

Comment: I tried this method with SWT 4.3. Strangely enough it only works for some of the dlls that are unpacked. Swt-awt-win32-4427.dll for example is writing to the new location I set, but strangely enough swt-win32-4427.dll is still unpacked in the user.home directory (if that is possible). If the user.home is not available I get a "Could not load SWT library" error.

Comment: I solved the problem by placing the required dlls manually in a known location and setting the swt.library.path property to this location. `System.setProperty("swt.library.path", "C:\\Temp\\");`

Answer (score -1):

Ok, I found the solution. The problem was about the dll generation. I was using 3.7m5 version, I downloaded a previous version (3.7) and the application ran properly.

Regards.